# Android Gradle 3.0 Plugin beta2 update breaks pickFirst

Tags: java, android, gradle, plugins

since i upgraded to gradle 3.0 beta2 plugin, i get the following exception:

```
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/servlet/Foo;
```

Foo here replaced with some duplicate javax servlet files. Until now i solved the issue with pickFirst, but since the plugin update, the old exception is present again. Does anyone know how to bypass this?

Edit:
Full setup is Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 with gradle 4.0 RC1 and gradle-plugin 3.0 beta 2

Comment: are you by any chance using leakcanary 1.5.2

Comment: No, i am not using leakcanary

Comment: I carefully added `{ exclude group: 'qqq.pararam' }` to all suspicious **implementation** statements until the error was gone.